# Rename operation was cancelled or invalid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 OS Build 18362.207.

I am trying to make a cross-platform Xamarin application using the "Master-Detail" project template.

After I create the project from the template, I want to rename the `<ProjectName>\Models\Item.cs` class to something more meaningful. However, any attempt to use the refactoring tools build into the IDE fails.

If I type in a name in place of the class name, and try and use the refactoring tools to rename the class `Item` to anything else (I have tried `Test`, `TestThingie`, `Conversation`, etc) and hover over the new name and click the Lightbulb and

"Rename `Item` to `Conversation`"

I immediately get a error that the rename operation was either cancelled or invalid. I can't imagine why though... Below is the log that I get with this error.

```
=====================
7/2/2019 10:34:46 PM
Recoverable
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: relativeSourceFilePath
   at Microsoft.Requires.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.HandleBeforeRefactorFailure(Int32 promptContinueOnFail, String relativeSourceFilePath, String errorMessage, HashSet`1 failedFiles)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass744_0.<<HandleBeforeRefactorNotify>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.ExecuteSynchronously[T](Func`1 asyncAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode.<>c__DisplayClass577_0.<HrInvoke>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.HResult.Invoke(Func`1 action, IServiceProvider vsShellServiceProvider, IProjectFaultHandlerService projectFaultHandlerService, UnconfiguredProject project)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
```

For clarity, my steps are

1. Open Visual Studio 2019
2. New Project
3. `Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)`
4. Go into `<ProjectName>\Models\Item.cs` and attempt to rename the `Item` class, using the lightbulb menu to change the name elsewhere
5. It fails

Am I doing something wrong? I would like not to have to rename a class in a thousand other places!

Comment: Have you filed a [Bug Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: Or checked if a bug report has already been filed?

Comment: A similar bug report was filed, and I added my details, though I'm not sure if it's related

Comment: I am using Resharper for VS2019 and no prob ... if you can try it, its worth the try.

Comment: @Umar3x Unfortunately I don't have access to ReSharper... Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @TylerGubala could you link the bug report. I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @AdrianBlackburn [here you go](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/583044/rename-refactoring-does-not-work-in-files-included.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way a solution but i believe this is a bug in VS 2019 when using Xamarin Forms if you have VS 2017 installed you can rename you files there, it worked for me.

Comment: It's worth noting that this does not refactor throughout the whole solution. For instance, when inside the `Models` folder and refactoring the names of properties, I had to not only change it in the Xaml (somewhat understandable) but also in the `ViewModels` as well.